# Как самоудалить папку с рабочего стола Apple MacBook по таймеру

Tags: ios, bash, macos, applescript

Нужно задать таймер и по его истечению удалить папку с файлами с рабочего стола и корзины. Apple MacBook не заметно. подскажите как реализовать данное решение. Спасибо!

Comment: А там `cron` есть?

Comment: @donRumata а зачем использовать крон, если это одноразовая операция? Тем более хотят сделать это `не заметно`

Comment: @VitaliyKalyuzhnyak, я походу прочитал наискось.

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно удалить по тайперу, то лучше запустить скрипт в бэкграунде через консоль. Пример:

```
sleep 100
rm -rf ~/Desktop/folder_name
rm -rf ~/.Trash/folder_name
rm -f my_script.sh
```

Закинуть этот код в файл `my_script.sh` и запустить

```
bash my_script.sh &
```

- `sleep 100` - 100 секунд
- `rm -rf ~/Desktop/folder_name` - удалит папку `folder_name` с
  рабочего стола
- `rm -rf ~/.Trash/folder_name` - удали папку `folder_name` с корзины
- `rm -f my_script.sh` - удалит файл скрипта `my_script.sh` (удалит сам
  себя).